# How to authenticate google login on backend

Tags: php, mysql, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am trying validate that a proper google login was made, with this information I want to get certain information from the Id_token and create a MySQL query so that they are verified on my own server (so i can set their permissions etc)
When I do this on my local server (xampp) with this code, it works perfectly:

[image]

But when I upload this same script to my own server, it will return a Internal 500 Server error when it reaches `$ticket = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);`

I have no idea why this is happening, both my live server and localhost are in the allowed javascript origins on my google dev:

[image]

Here is the full script:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: kenji
 * Date: 1/11/2017
 * Time: 10:51 AM
 */
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
//define('DBSERVER','localhost');
define('DBSERVER','matypatty.zapto.org');
define('DBUSERNAME','***');
define('DBPASSWORD','***');
define('DBNAME','***');
$conn = new mysqli(DBSERVER, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$CLIENT_ID = "***.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);
$client->setApplicationName("Backend_Auth");
if(isset($_POST['id_token']) && !(empty($_POST['id_token']))) {
    $id_token = $_POST['id_token'];
    $ticket = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
    if ($ticket) {
        $data = $ticket;
        print_r($data);

        /*$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM oauth_users WHERE id='".$payload['sub']."'");
        if (!$query) { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn)); }
        if(!(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO oauth_users (id, email, name, source, picture) VALUES ('" . $payload['sub'] . "', '" . $payload['email'] . "','" . $payload['name'] . "', '" . $payload['iss'] . "', '" . $payload['picture'] . "')";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        }*/
    }else{
        die("Not a valid id_token");
    }
}else{
    die("set id_token to post");
}
```

I am printing a fresh id_token for testing with my login function on my site so the post data is real, as shown in the localhost example

Answer (score 1):

Its because its an outdated version of PHP ):
Youre going to need a new host or use google token verification which will be slower